# Get Absolute java.nio.Path

Tags: java, file, java-8

Is there a way to get absolute java.nio.Path  ?
I have a relative path `path3` retrieved from  `Path path3 = path1.relativize(path2);`
I want to get again `path2` from `path1` and `path3` .

Will `path1.resolve(path3)` return `path2`?

For example **`path1.resolve(path3)`** :
if **path1** is `C:\Users\ABC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JSF Sample\web`
and **path3** is `..\..\..\..\Pictures\BxqfOHfIIAApI.png`
then **path2** contains `C:\Users\ABC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JSF Sample\web\..\..\..\..\Pictures\BxqfOHfIIAApI.png`

How to get **path2** like `C:\Users\ABC\Pictures\BxqfOHfIIAApI.png`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`path1.resolve(path3)` will get you a path that's equivalent but not necessarily equal to path2.  You may want to do `path1.resolve(path3).normalize()` instead.

```
path1 = Paths.get("/var");
path2 = Paths.get("/tmp");

path3 = path1.relativize(path2);  // path3 is "../tmp"
path4 = path1.resolve(path3);     // path4 is "/var/../tmp"

path5 = path4.normalize();        // path5 is "/tmp"
```

**Edit**:
Based on additional info in your edit, normalize() is exactly what you want.